# Drop down menu not closing jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

What I'm trying to do is a drop down menu, and the user click on of the items inside the menu automatically closes the menu, now if working but because I'm using the

to closes the menu is causing me a lot problem so I decide to change but it don't work.
Heres a demo http://jsfiddle.net/nWxe6/2/

This is function that works

```
 $("li").click(function(event)
  {
    $(this).closest("div").hide("slow"); 

  });
```

but this one doesn't

```
 $("hideM").click(function(event)
  {
    $(this).closest("div").hide("slow"); 

  });
```

Comment: it should be #hideM not hideM.

Comment: I would say thank you, and so ...

Answer (score 2):

Change this

```
$("hideM").click(function(event)
  {
    $(this).closest("div").hide("slow"); 

  });
```

To

```
$("#hideM").click(function(event){

    $(this).closest("div").hide("slow"); 

  });
```

If you are using `id` as your `jquery` selector , you need to prefix `#`.

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/5EQzs/)**

Answer (score 1):

You need to add "#" as shown below...

```
$("#hideM").click(function(event)
  {
    $(this).closest("div").hide("slow"); 

  });
```

Demo :- http://jsfiddle.net/5EQzs/1/

Answer (score 1):

You're missing '#'. Currently you are trying to use a HTML element 'hideM', which doesn't exist. To use your element with ID 'hideM', you have to use

```
$("#hideM").click(function(event) {
    $(this).closest("div").hide("slow");
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nWxe6/3/)